# If i upgrade my ubuntu to non-beta version, will my installed software lost?

Tags: upgrade

my software lost when i upgrade to ubuntu to 12.10 beta version. Will my software lost if i upgrade to non-beta version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade from the CD/ISO all of your software will be removed as the Upgrade feature on the CD is actually just a reinstall without formatting. Your files will be kept intact.

If you upgrade using update manager, to a beta, alpha, pre-alpha or even a normal release, locally installed software will sometimes be determined by the system to no longer be needed and removed. Software(s) with unmet dependencies in the new distribution might also be removed during the upgrade to a beta version where the repository is still constantly changing.

Comment: In general, no your software won't be removed, but the packages will be upgraded, which could be a different experience. A package *could* be removed if it's dropped from the archive, or for some reason is incompatible. But this is the rare case.